# Duda con Casting de una función en C

Tags: c

muy buenas. Lo dicho en el título, me gustaría que por favor me resuelvan esta duda. Tengo una estructura la cual es para hacer una lista:

```
typedef struct
{
  Elemento *p;            // elemento de cabecera
  Elemento *elemAnterior; // elemento anterior
  Elemento *elemActual;   // elemento actual
} tllseo;
```

luego la función:

```
void mostrarLista(tllseo *lista) {
    //Mostrar todos los nombres de la lista


    Datos *alumnos = (Datos*)obtenerPrimero(lista);
    //El puntero alumno de tpo dato contiene ahora el valor devuelto por la función obtenerPrimero

    while (alumno) {
        printf("%s %g%\n", alumnos->nombre, alumnos->nota);
        alumnos = (Datos*)obtenerSiguiente(lista);  //Mientras haya alumnos me mostrarálas notas

    }

}
```

que llama a:

```
void *obtenerPrimero(tllseo *lista)
{
  // Devolver un puntero a los datos del primer elemento
  // Si la lista está vacía, devolver NULL
  if ( listaVacia(lista) ) return NULL;
  lista->elemActual = lista->elemAnterior = lista->p;
  return lista->p->datos;
}
```

Mi pregunta es, la linea que pone:

```
Datos *alumnos = (Datos*)obtenerPrimero(lista);
```

¿Esto es un casting? perdonen por la ignorancia. No entiendo por qué se realiza esta linea. `Datos` corresponde a otra estructura,¿ por qué al llamar a la función le antepone `(Datos*)`?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Por favor, en adelante evita etiquetar preguntas como [tag:c++] si estás preguntando por [tag:c], C y C++ no son el mismo lenguaje.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Respuesta corta: Sí.**

La intención de un cast es "forzar" el tipo del valor a la derecha para que "encaje" en el tipo de la izquierda; considerando la misma línea que mencionas:

```
Datos *alumnos = (Datos*)obtenerPrimero(lista);
```

El tipo de dato de la variable alumnos es `Datos *`. Ahora fijemonos en la cabecera de la función `obtenerPrimero(tllseo *)`:

```
void *obtenerPrimero(tllseo *lista);
```

Retorna `void *` o un *puntero a `void`*, es decir, que el tipo *debajo<sup>1</sup>* puede ser cualquier cosa, no necesariamente un puntero a `Datos`, por lo que el cast es para especificar que el tipo de destino.

**Ahora bien, ¿Por qué se hace este cast?**

A pesar de ser innecesario *(No totalmente para este caso)*, como mencioné anteriormente se "obliga" al valor de retorno a ser del tipo de la variable/puntero de destino, considera el siguiente código [(ideone aquí)](https://ideone.com/GyCow1):

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct TEST { int X; int Y; } Punto;
typedef struct TEST2 { int64_t Z; } Direccion;

int main(void) {
  Punto N = { .X = 0xAAAA1000, .Y = 0xBBBB1000 };
  Direccion *Dir = (Direccion *)&N;  /* Obligamos a cambiar el tipo de N. */

  printf("Punto.X: 0x%08X, Punto.Y: 0x%08X\n", N.X, N.Y);
  printf("Dir.Z: 0x%016" PRIx64 "\n", Dir->Z);

  return 0;
}
```

El resultado debe ser:

```
Punto.X: 0xAAAA1000, Punto.Y: 0xBBBB1000
Dir.Z: 0xbbbb1000aaaa1000
```

Se puede apreciar que a pesar de que el tipo de ambas variables es distinto, al hacer el cast, se "cambia" el tipo del valor.

El valor de `Dir.Z` el mismo de tanto `Punto.X` como `Punto.Y` "fusionados", esto es porque el código ejecutable no sabe de tipos, pero si de direcciones de memoria y como calcularlas, entonces el compilador, al reconocer un cast, se encarga de cambiar los calculos de las direcciones en base al tipo que tienes a la mano.

<sup>1: Traducción directa de *underlying*.</sup>

**Referencias**

- [Conversión de tipos](http://www.carlospes.com/curso_de_lenguaje_c/01_08_01_02_conversion_de_tipo.php)
- [Conversiones en C](http://programacionnerd.blogspot.com/2012/05/c-conversiones-de-tipo-casting-en-c.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta @NaCi, voy comprendiendo de a poco esto.

Comment: Si te ha ayudado la respuesta, considera marcarla como aceptada en la palomilla justo debajo de las flechas para votar en la respuesta :)